# Android Toolbar.mTitleText VS Toolbar.mTitleTextView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working to make Toolbar title multiline.(Without a CustomView).

I figured that Toolbar has a `mTitleText` field and a `mTitleTextView` field.

I tried to make `mTitleTextView` multiline using reflection:

```
TextView titletextview;
        try{
            Field field = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField( "mTitleTextView" );
            field.setAccessible( true );
            titletextview = (TextView)field.get( toolbar );
            titletextview.setText(R.string.app_name);
            titletextview.setSingleLine( false );
            titletextview.setMaxLines( 2 );
            titletextview.setEllipsize( TextUtils.TruncateAt.END );
        }catch( Exception e ) {
            Log.e(detail_test.class.toString(), "", e );
        }
```

(I don't know It is working or not because `mTitleTextView` is not shown in toolbar. detail below.)

If I am not wrong, these lines of code sets the **mTitleText** field of Toolbar and display in toolbar

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
```

Now, After when I set `mTitleTextView.mText` to some other string, `toolbar.mTitleText` and `toolbar.mTitleTextView.mText` both are different.
[image]
 Which is OK. But I can only see `toolbar.mTitleText` string "ActionBarTest" on screen.

Now, How can I bring up `mTitleTextView` in Toolbar? What am I missing here?

Comment: Your question is not clear. How are you determining that "`mTitleTextView` is not shown in toolbar"? It looks like you're setting the same text in both places. "After when I set `mTitleTextView.mText` to some other string." - How are you doing that, exactly? That is, why are you referring to that specific, private field? Are you using reflection for that, as well?

Comment: "After when I set mTitleTextView.mText to some other string." I am doing this with reflection.

Toolbar.mTitleText is being set with `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);`

When I run/debug the app, Toolbar.mTitleText string is shown as Title.(different from Toolbar.mTitleTextView.mText). 
So what is the use of Toolbar.mTitleTextView? 
I simply need to have Multiline Title in Toolbar. I have found the solution using reflection but it seems toolbar is not using `mTitleTextView` to set Title.

Comment: A `TextView` won't invalidate/redraw itself if you set the `mText` field directly. Just use `setText()`. `mTitleTextView` is the `TextView` the title is in, so I have to assume that the problem is somewhere else in your code. The reflection snippet you've shown is fine.

Comment: When I inspect toolbar object in debug mode:
There are two members/fields:
 
`toolbar.mTitleText`,   

`toolbar.mTitleTextView (setText() using reflection here)`

Example:
`toolbar.mTitleText` is set to "ABC", 
`toolbar.mTitleTextView.mText` is set to XYZ (using `setText()` and Reflection). 

while app is running, on mobile screen ABC is shown in toolbar. or toolbar is Empty when I use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`.  I need XYZ instead( that is why I am using Reflection.)

Comment: This is the result I get running the code you've posted on a `Toolbar` with the title initially set to a single line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ96Q.png.

Comment: Okay. I will dig into this further. You may be right. Some other thing may be bugging around. Thanks.

Comment: I have created a new sample and failed to produce the required results. 
Can you please look at the code. Or point out issues with the code. [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/omerasif57/actionbartest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/intrcptr/actionbartest/MainActivity.java).
[activity_main.xml](https://github.com/omerasif57/actionbartest/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml).